# HTML5 Canvas todataURL too large

Tags: jquery, mysql, html, canvas

I am using WolframHempel's photobooth.js plugin to display a webcam in the browser.  I want to then capture the contents of the webcam canvas using jquery's todataurl() and then store the image in a mysql text field.  My problem is that the todataurl() method returns a string of about 100,000 characters but the limit on the text field in mysql is ~65K characters.

My canvas dimensions are 250px x 200px.

Is there a way to compress or otherwise resize the output image captured from the canvas?

```
var canvas  = document.getElementById("punch_canvas");
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

$.ajax ({
  //send image and other form data to mysql via php
})
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to change your MySQL database to use MEDIUMTEXT instead of TEXT.

Comment: There are some compression algorithms that have been implemented in JavaScript, but there are quick a few issues with using it on a base64 image. You can Google around for it, but your best scenario is changing the size of the database field if possible.

Comment: Thanks Robert! I had my focus on exact wrong side of the transaction.  Worked like a charm.

Comment: Just to mention...The default image type of .toDataURL is PNG.  You can alternatively specify JPG to get a smaller file size: .toDataURL("image/jpeg").  You can even add a second parameter to specify the JPG quality desired:  .toDataURL("image/jpeg",0.25);